# Dataset of MNIST not found from Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I have a python script whose initial lines read

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf
```

When I run the script it gives this error

> 'no module such as tensorflow.tutorials.examples.mnist'.

I have already pip installed Tensorflow, what do i do now?

Comment: Are you sure that TensorFlow is working? Please try 'import tensorflow as tf', followed by 'print(tf.__version__)' in Python. If you get an error, then there is probably a problem with your TensorFlow installation.

Comment: I uninstalled and installed it again,still same error. Where do I run my script? I tried using windows command prompt and python and anaconda command line, isn't working :(

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I can see that you are using Anaconda. Have you tried to install it with `conda install tensorflow`? Also, you could try to create an environment first, and install tensorflow afterwards with `conda create -n tensorflow pip python=2.7` (or 3.x depending on your system) within it.